# SOSL Behaving Differently in Spring16 vs Winter16

Tags: sosl, pre-release

Has anyone else noticed a difference in SOSL on a Spring16 prerelease org? The code has not changed for over a year yet our custom search page has stopped finding results for search strings our end users commonly use.

We have compared our full copy to live (the only difference being the pre-release) and live still works as we expect.

Has anyone noticed this or maybe understand what could be the cause?

**UPDATE**

This was confirmed as a bug by Salesforce and was patched before the Spring16 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOSL is by its nature a fuzzy search mechanism.

The underlying indexes can change overtime, and search results are often ranked on more frequently accessed records. This is detailed in the [SOSL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.192.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm).

Either one of these factors could explain a difference in search behavior in an org cloned from your production org.

However, anytime a pre-release org is displaying suspicious behavior it is prudent to raise a case to support. Pre-release is not GA, it is pre-release. One of the reasons we pre-release is so that we can discover problems before the actual product release date.

Comment: Thanks Peter I have raised a Case now but was just interested if it was just me